# How to get primary key instantly after create using sql for another sql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new, please be merciful.
In my case, I have two tables both of which are quite the same. Just one of them is contains the user, but the other one is only for a specific user. 
Here is my problem, after user registers account, how do i get the primary key(auto generate by the table) for the first SQL and use it in second SQL to store in different table.

Is there any problem with the coding? Because i can't create the patient.

Comment: There should be a last insert ID function depending on the driver (mysqli, PDO) you are using.

Comment: What is the data type of your primary key?

Comment: The data type for my primary key is int

Comment: Well, by _"auto generate"_, i'd suppose you mean auto_increment on an int primary key. Look into `mysqli_insert_id($conn);`

Comment: You can find the max(primary key column value) from the table which has all user information and use this for other table

Comment: @chris85 Hi, so you means i cant instantly get the primary key and store it?

Comment: @CJYeo Yes, the driver should have the id accessible to it after the execution, unless the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i think i found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check the PHP manual (or at least google) before asking for functions existence:

For MySQLi:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

For PDO:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

There is a function for MySQL too, but since the driver is old and deprecated, please consider using one of above.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'm so sorry.